# How to pass values to a generator in a for loop?

Tags: python, generator

I know that you can use `.send(value)` to send values to an generator.  I also know that you can iterate over a generator in a for loop.  Is it possible to pass values to a generator while iterating over it in a for loop?

What I'm trying to do is

```
def example():
    previous = yield
    for i range(0,10):
        previous = yield previous*i

t = example()
for value in example"...pass in a value?...":
    "...do something with the result..."
```

Comment: Have you tried it what was the result... you can't send a value in the `for` statement. But you could use `while`.

Comment: If I use a while loop, I need to catch a `StopIteration` which adds a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: And you feel the nested generator is more comprehensible code?

Comment: Yes?  Feel free to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You technically could, but the results would be confusing. eg:

```
def example():
    previous = (yield)
    for i in range(1,10):
        received = (yield previous)
        if received is not None:
            previous = received*i


t = example()
for i, value in enumerate(t):
  t.send(i)
  print value
```

Outputs:

```
None
0
2
8
18
```

Dave Beazley wrote an [amazing article](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf) on coroutines (**tldr;  don't mix generators and coroutines in the same function**)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.  The trick is to create an additional generator that wraps `t.send(value)` in a for loop `(t.send(value) for value in [...])`.

```
def example():
    previous = yield
    for i in range(0,10):
        previous = yield previous * i

t = examplr()
t.send(None)
for i in (t.send(i) for i in ["list of objects to pass in"]):
    print i
```

Comment: Obviously some cut a paste errors here `test()` isn't defined and you have an extra `)` on the `for` statement.

Comment: @AChampion:   and even when those issues are fixed, it produces nothing

Comment: Change the `["list ..."]` to a sensible list and it should.

Comment: @AChampion:  yes, that's better.